# Neither cat or pg will work

Tags: bash

I'm on an unfamiliar server running a bash shell and I cannot use either pg or cat to view a file.

When I run `pg filename`, I get "command not found".  When I run `man cat`, I get the normal instructions.

I've test `cat -A filname` with no success.

Comment: Why can't you use `cat`? What happens when you run `cat -A filname`?

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
command -p cat <file
```

...if run in a POSIX environment the `command -p` invocation is guaranteed to find all of the standard utilities. If that doesn't work, burn your computer.

To get your system's standard `$PATH` *(as should be set by `login`)*:

```
PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try less:

```
less <file you want to view>
```

or more:

```
more <file you want to view>
```

Also verify that you have permission to view the file.